# Python - Sorting over Single array/list vs multidimensional array/list

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I'm trying to understand why the below code is throwing  when trying to sort a single list, but it works for the multidimensional list. Is the iteration over the single list trying to sort each value in the list whereas the iteration over the multiple lists is actually sorting each array rather than each value in the arrays ?

```
multilist = [[0,3,-1,9],[4,2,77,55],[22,-11]]
for i in multilist:
    print(sorted(i))

singlelist = [0,-44,21]
for i in singlelist:
    print(sorted(i))
```

Output:

```
[-1, 0, 3, 9]
[2, 4, 55, 77]
[-11, 22]

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)

 26 singlelist = [0,-44,21]
 27 for i in singlelist:
 ---> 28     print(sorted(i))
 29 #print(test)

 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Try and step through what you have in each variable at each line when the code is run. The error is pretty explicit.

Comment: `sorted` function works on iterables (e.g. list). But an `int` is not an iterable. As `i` becomes a single `int` in case of single dimension list, the exception is thrown only then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `singlelist` is 1 dimensionnal array, `i` is an int which is not iterable. So it can't be sorted. You can simply do this

```
multilist = [[0,3,-1,9],[4,2,77,55],[22,-11]]
for i in multilist:
    print(sorted(i))

singlelist = [0,-44,21]
print(sorted(singlelist))
```

And it sorts everything fine

Comment: That's what I was figuring and wanted to see if I was following the right logic. So it makes sense. Thanks for the clarifications you guys!

Comment: You're welcome @K_Bx, please remember to validate the answer